# write.csv formatting dates r

Tags: r, csv

I have a dataframe with a date column 'StartDate' formatted as:
2014-12-31

I want to write a CSV that has StartDate formatted the same way. However, write.csv() writes StartDate in the format
12/31/2014.

How can I prevent this behavior?

Thks.

Comment: Are you opening CSV file using Excel? Try using text editor Notepad.

Comment: Yes I am. And, per your suggestion, the hyphen is still there in Notepad. So the problem is Excel's formatting of dates. I will look at the Excel options to see if this is configurable. Thanks for the lead.

Comment: Yes, Excel converts data types implicitly.

Comment: Any ideas how to override this?

Comment: Maybe try the text import wizard of Excel (for me it's under the "Data" tab but I guess it will depend on the version that you are using)

Comment: Also beware of Excel saving in a different format than it displays after converting, typically DD/MM/YY - potential data loss!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments on your original question, this seems like a problem with formatting in excel. You can change the date format to any style you like in excel by following the directions [here](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Format-a-date-the-way-you-want-8e10019e-d5d8-47a1-ba95-db95123d273e)

Comment: T2Tom -- thanks. That is the answer. Would vote you up if I could.

Comment: You may be able to "accept as answer" by clicking the tick below the upvote/downvote buttons next to my answer, if you are satisfied. I would further recommend you edit the question suitably to reflect what you neally need.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful for me,

```
require ("dplyr", "readr")
    write_tsv (
                 data %>%
                 replace ( 
                          sapply (data, function(x)inherits(x, "Date")),
                          format (
                                    data [sapply(data, function(x)inherits(x, "Date"))], 
                                    "%Y/%m/%d"
                          )
                  )
```

but I need in txt format (because I used it with a next SQL parser in R)